# Modal background distortion

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

Issue: When showing a Modal in the browser, the background gets distorted when it’s in full screen mode (see picture). This only happens on some machines. On my local machine I get the distortion, but on my Virtual machine everything looks fine even though I’m using exactly the same version of Chrome 61.0.3163.100.

Has anyone experienced this, and have a solution?

[image: Distorted background]